# Cloud document ai

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, cloud-document-ai

I was learning about the google document and I need it for invoice ocr. I've used the given java code and tried to get extracted text from my respective document. But I want to get the json output and what if this document ai doesn't provide the correct result so what can i do for that ?

I've tried the given JAVA code for Process documents by using client libraries (JAVA) and got the extracted output in my eclipse result window.
1.How to get that output in json format
2.How to get the correct or improve the accuracy of output if the extracted data is not correct or some of the data isn't correct

Comment: Could you try this [code](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#code_samples_2) for your requirement? For detailed information on output produced by processors you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/output#processor_Invoice%20Parser). Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: Hi @DushyantAneja, Did the above comment help you?

Answer (score 0):

For your two main questions:

1. Get [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) output in JSON format.

   - You have two main options:

     - If you use [batch processing](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#batch-process), the response from Document AI will be in Google Cloud Storage in a JSON file already.
     - If you're using [online processing](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#online-process), then you can use the [`JsonFormat`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/protobuf/latest/com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat#com_google_protobuf_util_JsonFormat_printer__) class from the [`com.google.protobuf.util`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/protobuf/latest/overview) library to get the response into JSON.
2. Verify or Improve the results of the processor

   - You can use [Human-in-the-Loop](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/hitl) to send documents to a Human Review team based on the confidence value.
   - You can use [Uptraining](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/training-overview#uptrain) to create custom versions of a supported processor with additional training data to improve accuracy or extract custom fields.

I recommend checking out the [videos and labs](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/videos) and the [Overview](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/overview) listed in the documentation for introductions to the concepts/features of Document AI.